# Show output of a command run inside screen if it exits with errors

Tags: shell, terminal, gnu-screen

I am using the `screen` command for starting server running in foreground. But in case there is an error when starting server I am not able to see the output of command. I have to run it again without `screen`.

```
foo@ubuntu:~/server/application$ screen -S server ruby start.rb true 3001
[screen is terminating]
foo@ubuntu:~/server/application$
```

I would like to see STDERR/STDOUT output on screen even if when using `screen` even if the screened command fails. Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

How will you know that the server has started successfully, and is not about to die with an error message?

If you want to show the screen session until explicitly killed, it's easy. Run a command that doesn't terminate after the `ruby` command, for example to run a shell:

```
screen -S server sh -c 'ruby start.rb true 3001; echo "Server terminated with status $?"; exec bash'
```

or to exit after a timeout

```
screen -S server sh -c 'ruby start.rb true 3001; echo "Server terminated with status $?"; sleep 3600'
```

If you want to detach after a timeout even if the server keeps running:

```
screen -S server sh -c '
  ruby start.rb true 3001 &
  server_pid=$!
  sleep 2
  if [ -z "$(ps -o pid= -p "$server_pid")" ]; then
    wait
    echo "Server terminated with status $?"
    exec bash
  fi
'
```

Answer (score 1):

Ah yes. When you start and stop `screen` it resets the screen display, clearing it in the process. The easiest way to ensure that you can see errors generated by your `ruby` command is to separate it from the `screen` command, so that one is no longer dependent on the other:

```
screen -S server
ruby start.rb true 3001
...
exit
```

You will presumably already know that <kbd>Ctrl A</kbd><kbd>d</kbd> will detach the screen, and later you can reattach this named session with `screen -r server`.

Errors that may be generated by the `ruby` command will remain available for perusal. Even if the command exits the `screen` session will remain running, so it's important to remember to reattach and `exit` when you have finished.

Comment: Thank you for answer, unfortunately this does not work for me since it would be easier to do it "my way" -> try screen command, if it does not work try without screen. Also it created some problems I somehow created too many screen sessions ... hoping for one-liner answer.

Comment: @Dolphin if you keep running `screen -S server` you will get new sessions. Run `screen -r server` to reattach to an existing session at a later date. Run `screen -ls` to see if the session already exists. It wouldn't be hard to encapsulate "attach to existing session or start new session" in a short script. But if you do `screen ... ruby ...` then when the `ruby` command exits so will `screen`.